# Send event to particular browser/user using RabbitMQ Web STOMP plugin without Socket.IO

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I have connected 4 browsers with RabbitMQ connection. Now i want to send event broadcasting to particular browser. is it possible?

I am sending event to all browsers by following code

```
 function test(){
      data = $('#msg').val();
      client.send('/topic/testMessage', {"content-type":"text/plain"}, data);  
      // exchange - routingkey    /temp-queue, /exchange, /topic, /queue, /amq/queue, /reply-queue/ 
  }
  var on_connect = function(x) { 
      id = client.subscribe("/topic/testMessage", function(d) {
           print_first(d.body);
      });    
  };
```

**How i can send request to particular browser/user ? is it possible to brodcast event to single browser ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send event to particular browser/a particular tab in browser by changing subscribe call from :

```
client.subscribe("/topic/testMessage");
```

to

```
client.subscribe("/topic/testMessage" + browserId);
```

where browserId would be a uniqueId to the tab in the browser and the server would push the result on the exchange  with this browserId appended in the routing  Key.

Currently you are using a commonId (testMessage) , and why all the browsers have subsribed on exchange with this routing key, thus all are recieving  the message.